# An example of a set of points in $R^3$ which is not open, not closed, not convex and not bounded

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I can't seem to think of an example for this set. 
An example of a set of points in $R^3$ which is not open, not closed, not convex and not bounded

Comment: How about $\{(x,y,z):x\gt0,y=x^2,z=0\}$?

Comment: How about $\{(2^n,0,0):n\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Answer (score 4):

This works: $\mathbb{Q}^3$ ....

Answer (score 0):

Take the open ball of radius 1, plus the line $(x,0,0)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Precisely, $X=\{(x,y,z): y=z=0 \text{ or } x^2+y^2+z^2<1 \}$. This is

- not bounded, because you have the infinite line;
- not open, because any ball around $(22,0,0)$ contain $(22,\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some epsilon, which is not in $X$.
- not closed, because the succession $x_n = (0,0,1-(1/n))$ has limit $(0,0,1)$ which is not in X
- not convex, because the middle point between $(0,0,1/2)$ and $(2,0,0)$, i.e. $(1,0,1/4)$, it is not in X.

Answer (score 0):

A *symmetric* example:

Let $B_r(p) = \{ x\in\mathbb R^3 : |x-p|\leq r \}$ and define
$$X = \bigcup_{n\geq1} (B_{2n}(0)\setminus B_{2n-1}(0)).$$

Thus $X$ isn't open, nor closed, nor convex, nor bounded.